# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Expectation failure on verify: finalize(): expected: 1, actual: 0

Tags: java, splunk, easymock, finalize

I have an old test in code which uses EasyMock instead of Mockito.
When I run test locally then it works, however when it runs in gitlab pipeline then I get:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    finalize(): expected: 1, actual: 0
    finalize(): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.verify(MocksControl.java:184)
    at myproject.mocks.EasyMockTestCase.verify(EasyMockTestCase.java:72)
    at myproject.controllers.TestController.userIsAbleToSave(TestController.java:132)
```

of course I can see a lot of the same questions on stackoverflow and in the net but here it's strange because of `finalize()` method.

My code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ACTION, params = "buttonSubmit")
    @Secured(Permissions.UPDATE_INSTRUMENT)
    public ModelAndView buttonSubmit(TypeRequest typeRequest, final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mav = getView();
        Product product;
        try {
            product = productLifeCycleService.createNew(new AppRequest(request));
        } catch (DuplicateException e) {
            return handleDuplicate(typeRequest, request, false, e);
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            return handleValidation(request, false, e);
        }
        return redirectToProductDetail(mav, product.getId());
    }
```

and test for this:

```
@Test
    public void userIsAbleToSave() throws Exception {
        expect(productLifeCycleService.createNew((Request)anyObject())).andStubReturn(product);
        expect(product.getId()).andStubReturn(STANDARD);
        TypeRequest typeRequest = new TypeRequest (QQ, HH, GOAL);

        replay();
        underTest.buttonSubmit(typeRequest, httpRequest);
        verify();
    }
```

Why is it failing on `finalize()`, why it works locally and don't work on Gitlab? It started to fail in pipeline after adding `appender` to connect to Splunk in `logback.xml`.

When product is created this way:

```
Product product;
product = productLifeCycleService.createNew(new AppRequest(request));
```

it's also not easy to use Mockito here.

@Edit
I see that adding into `logback.xml`:

```
<appender-ref ref="http"/>
```

spoil test. In `@Before` I have `mockHttpRequest()` method which do:

```
private void mockHttpRequest() {
        httpRequest = mock(MockHttpServletRequest.class);
        expect(httpRequest.getRequestURI()).andStubReturn(URI);
        expect(httpRequest.getHeader(HEADER)).andStubReturn(null);
        expect(httpRequest.getParameter(TYPE)).andStubReturn(TypeName.LEGAL.getFormName());
        expect(httpRequest.getMethod()).andStubReturn(POST);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really strange. It it expecting `finalize`. It means that an expectation was set for it. But I don't see an expectation set. So it could be that it is set somewhere else in your code, or that it's called by the GC while you are setting your expectations. But I doubt it, because it wouldn't be in the same thread.

So my assumption is that a `finalize` is expected somewhere else and should be `expectLastCall().andStubReturn()` instead of just `mock.finalize()`.

Comment: I checked the whole project and there is no single `finalize` in any java class. Indeed it's strange - especially the only change I did was adding new appender to log to Splunk and as I mentioned above - it fails only on Gitlab pipeline, locally it works

Answer (score 0):

It was really old EasyMock version: https://github.com/easymock/easymock/issues/32, upgrading fix the issue.